# Opening a password protected PDF Document

Tags: pdf, adobe, password-protection

How do I programmatically open a password protected PDF. I want to use ruby to open a password protected PDF and read its content.

I would like to know whether its possible and if it is possible guidance on the right way to do it

Comment: You supply a password. And unless you're using a PDF reading library, you're gonna have a LOT of fun.

Comment: @LukeN  Thanks for helping me out in the initial googling search parameters

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you got anywhere with this but pdf-reader supports this functionality.

You can see the full discussion leading to the feature here: https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/pull/18